# Are you allowed to kill the Ender Dragon in any SMP?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-bedrock-edition

I'm in an argument with my friend about dong this, and I want to find out if it's allowed or not, thanks in advance you all!

Comment: We can't answer this question

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it isn't even an answerable question.

Answer (score 5):

Rules of the server - as long as not contradicting Minecraft EULA - are set by the server's owner. And sometimes, on some servers they can be outright bizarre. So I wouldn't be surprised on some of them the first dragon is declared untouchable.

What is much more common, though, is that the dragon has been killed already - and on a lot of SMPs, especially ones running for a long time, the central End island has been thoroughly transformed and painstakingly decorated by the players - using blocks destructible by the dragon (obsidian and endstone are two of very few exceptions to the rule - the dragon destroys most block types it flies through). In these cases summoning the dragon would result in massive damage to the decor, and simply count as griefing. So it's not so much killing the dragon that is forbidden there, just the prerequisite for that: summoning it, and it's a rather common rule.